# Can't find all Elements with JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

In this assignment, the HTML page is given to me and I can't make changes to the HTML page. My task is to add an image into the website by using JQuery. The code is as given for the HTML page:

```html
 <!-- Sign Up  -->
  <template id="signUp">
    <form @submit.prevent='onSubmit' ref='form' action="" class='register-form'>
      <h2>New Account</h2>
      ...
      <input type="submit" :disabled='!isFormValid' value='Register'>
    </form>
  </template>

  <!-- Sign In  -->
  <template id="signinIn">
    <form ref='form' @submit.prevent='handleForm' action="" class='signin-form'>
      <h2>Sign In</h2>
      ...
      <input :disabled='!isFormValid' type="submit" value="Sign In">
    </form>
  </template>
```

The assignment want us to add an image above both the New Account and Sign In `h2` tag by using JQuery. I code is as followed:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log("Document ready");

  const $form = $("form");
  const $body = $("body");
  const $wrapper = $("<div class='wrapper flex-column'>");

  // function to add logo above form
  const addImage = (form) => {
    form.find("h2").prepend(`
      <div class='logo flex-row'>
        <img src='./assets/image.png' alt="logo" />
      </div>
    `);
  };

  // wrap body contents
  $body.wrapInner($wrapper);

  addImage($form);
});
```

The idea is to add the image above both the `h2` tag from sign up and sign in. The problem I'm running into is that I'm only getting one image above the New Account `h2` tag and not for both. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are  you using Vue? If so, update your tags please

Comment: I don't think so, this is just a class assignment with given HTML. Just have to create this JQuery and style with CSS ourselves.

Comment: Those two `<template>` tags at the top of your question are definitely using [tag:vue.js]. You really shouldn't mix jQuery with Vue

Comment: Those are just given to me. I'm just a student asked to style with CSS and make a JQuery adding the image.

Comment: Technically what you've got should work provided both forms are present in the document when your _ready_ handler runs. Given they're being rendered via Vue, that's definitely not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce all your jQuery code to the following:

```
$( "form h2" ).before("<div>hi</div>");
```

Then substitute the code you want for your image where I put the div for saying "hi".

This works by using the magic of the following:

jQuery selectors: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp

jQuery before() method: https://api.jquery.com/before/

For the selector, you're saying "give me all h2 elements that are within a form element". Then just execute the before() method on that returned list.